# Enforcing strictness in Haskell

Tags: haskell, exception, strict

While doing some TTD in Haskell, I recently developed the following function:

```
import Test.HUnit
import Data.Typeable
import Control.Exception

assertException :: (Show a) => TypeRep -> IO a -> Assertion
assertException errType fun = catch (fun >> assertFailure msg) handle
    where
    msg = show errType ++ " exception was not raised!"
    handle (SomeException e) [...]
```

The function takes a Type representation of an expected exception and an IO action. The problem is that most of the time I don't get the exception thrown even though I should have been, because of laziness. Often failing parts of `fun` are actually never evaluated here.

To remedy this i tried to replace `(fun >> assertFailure msg)` with `(seq fun $ assertFailure msg)`. I also tried to enable BangPatterns extension and put a bang before `fun` binding, but none of it helped. So how can I really force Haskell to evaluate `fun` strictly?

Comment: What does the code that *uses* `assertException` look like?

Comment: You probably want to use `try` instead of `catch`. That's at least the way `shouldThrow` is implemented in `Test.Hspec`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to distinguish between:

- Evaluating the value of type `IO a`
- Running the action represented by it, which may have side effects and returns a value of type `a`, and
- Evaluating the result of type `a` (or parts of it).

These always happen in that order, but not necessarily all of it. The code

```
foo1 :: IO a -> IO ()
foo1 f = do
   seq f (putStrLn "done")
```

will do only the first, while

```
foo2 :: IO a -> IO ()
foo2 f = do
   f -- equivalent to _ <- f
   putStrLn "done"
```

also does the second and finally

```
foo3 :: IO a -> IO ()
foo3 f = do
   x <- f 
   seq x $ putStrLn "done"
```

also does the third (but the usual caveats of using `seq` on a complex data type like lists apply).

Try these arguments and observe that `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` treat them differently.

```
f1 = error "I am not a value"
f2 = fix id -- neither am I
f3 = do {putStrLn "Something is printed"; return 42}
f4 = do {putStrLn "Something is printed"; return (error "x has been evaluated")}
f5 = do {putStrLn "Something is printed"; return (Just (error "x has been deeply evaluated"))}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to force the value to its normal form, not just its weak head normal form. For example, evaluating `Just (error "foo")` to WHNF won't trigger the exception, it'll just evaluate `Just`. I'd use the combination of [`evaluate`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Control-Exception-Base.html#v:evaluate) (which allows to properly sequence forced evaluation with `IO` actions) and [`rnf`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/deepseq-1.3.0.2/docs/Control-DeepSeq.html#v:rnf) (or `force` if you'd need the value for something):

```
assertException :: (Show a) => TypeRep -> IO a -> Assertion
assertException errType fun =
    catch (fun >>= evaluate . rnf >> assertFailure msg) handle
  where ...
```

However, be careful, as `assertFailure` [is implemented](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HUnit-1.2.5.2/docs/src/Test-HUnit-Lang.html#assertFailure) using exceptions, so wrapping into the `catch` block might catch it as well. So I'd suggest to evaluate the computation using `try` and call `assertFailure` outside the `try` block:

```
import Test.HUnit
import Data.Typeable
import Control.DeepSeq
import Control.Exception

assertException :: (NFData a, Show a) => TypeRep -> IO a -> Assertion
assertException errType fun =
    (try (fun >>= evaluate . rnf) :: IO (Either SomeException ())) >>= check
  where
    check (Right _) =
        assertFailure $ show errType ++ " exception was not raised!"
    check (Left (SomeException ex))
      | typeOf ex == errType    = return () -- the expected exception
      | otherwise               = assertFailure
                                    $ show ex ++ " is not " ++ show errType
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that `assertFailure` was implemented as an Exception and it was bothering me a bit that I had to catch and reraise it in handle, but that was best thing I could think of now and I decided to deal with forcing evaluation first, as it was greater problem. Thanks for solving the other by the way. :)